# Monthly Average column in Power BI/Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a column that will take the monthly average of a different column and have it repeat as a daily number. I need to multiply these numbers against a daily stock price.

```
CALCULATE (
        AVERAGE('Prepay Contracts'[Daily Gas]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Date Table', 'Date Table'[Month]))" 


should work, but all it does is repeat the [daily gas] prices. 


  CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE('Prepay Contracts'[Daily Gas ]),

        ALLEXCEPT('Date Table', 'Date Table'[Month]))
```

I had a temporary fix of just going into Excel and dragging (=Average) over the dates and repeating for all of the days of the month. So if the average for Jan. is 20, Jan 1 is 20, Jan 2 is also 20.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a variable MonthlyAverage to calculate the average of 'Daily Gas' for all rows up to the current row based on the date. Then multiply MonthlyAverage with the corresponding 'Daily Stock Price' from the 'Stock Price' table using the RELATED function like below:

```
Adjusted Gas Price =
VAR MonthlyAverage =
    AVERAGEX(
        FILTER('Prepay Contracts', 'Prepay Contracts'[Date] <= EARLIER('Prepay Contracts'[Date])),
        'Prepay Contracts'[Daily Gas]
    )
RETURN
    MonthlyAverage * RELATED('Stock Price'[Daily Stock Price])
```

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work.

Comment: @JohnBradley can you please share your input/expected output and your model ?